# how to concatenate string and variable into a variable in groovy

Tags: groovy

I need to concatenate string and variable into a boolean variable in groovy,
The case is like that:

I have a loop that looking for a pattern if the pattern exists I get a variable called **cname** that holds a certain value.

Now I want to use this value to create a new boolean parameter that contains the value of the **cname** parameter in the boolean parameter name.

This is what I tried:

```
boolean "trigger-${cname}" = true
boolean "trigger-"+${cname} = true
```

But it doesn't seem to work on a boolean.
I want to be able to have N parameters (as much as **cname** times) with the value true.
For example, if **cname** is (app, test, rest, .. N), then all the boolean parameters listed below will be ***true***:

```
trigger-app
trigger-test
trigger-rest
trigger-N
```

Comment: Why don't you store this information in say a Map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use quoted identifier to define a standard variable. Here is the part from Groovy Syntax documentation that explains it in details:

> ### 3. Identifiers
>
> #### 3.1. Normal identifiers
>
> Identifiers start with a letter, a dollar or an underscore. They cannot start with a number.
>
> A letter can be in the following ranges:
>
> - 'a' to 'z' (lowercase ascii letter)
> - 'A' to 'Z' (uppercase ascii letter)
> - '\u00C0' to '\u00D6'
> - '\u00D8' to '\u00F6'
> - '\u00F8' to '\u00FF'
> - '\u0100' to '\uFFFE'
>
> Then following characters can contain letters and numbers.
>
> Here are a few examples of valid identifiers (here, variable names):
>
> ```
> def name
> def item3
> def with_underscore
> def $dollarStart
> ```
>
> But the following ones are invalid identifiers:
>
> ```
> def 3tier
> def a+b
> def a#b
> ```
>
> All keywords are also valid identifiers when following a dot:
>
> ```
> foo.as
> foo.assert
> foo.break
> foo.case
> foo.catch
> ```
>
> ---
>
> <sup>Source: https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_normal_identifiers</sup>

However, when you define a `Map` you can use quoted identifiers to access its key-values.

> #### 3.2. Quoted identifiers
>
> Quoted identifiers appear after the dot of a dotted expression. For instance, the name part of the `person.name` expression can be quoted with `person."name"` or `person.'name'`. This is particularly interesting when certain identifiers contain illegal characters that are forbidden by the Java Language Specification, but which are allowed by Groovy when quoted. For example, characters like a dash, a space, an exclamation mark, etc.
>
> ```
> def map = [:]
>
> map."an identifier with a space and double quotes" = "ALLOWED"
> map.'with-dash-signs-and-single-quotes' = "ALLOWED"
>
> assert map."an identifier with a space and double quotes" == "ALLOWED"
> assert map.'with-dash-signs-and-single-quotes' == "ALLOWED"
> ```
>
> As we shall see in the following section on strings, Groovy provides different string literals. All kind of strings are actually allowed after the dot:
>
> ```
> map.'single quote'
> map."double quote"
> map.'''triple single quote'''
> map."""triple double quote"""
> map./slashy string/
> map.$/dollar slashy string/$
> ```
>
> There’s a difference between plain character strings and Groovy’s GStrings (interpolated strings), as in that the latter case, the interpolated values are inserted in the final string for evaluating the whole identifier:
>
> ```
> def firstname = "Homer"
> map."Simpson-${firstname}" = "Homer Simpson"
>
> assert map.'Simpson-Homer' == "Homer Simpson"
> ```
>
> ---
>
> <sup>Source: https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_quoted_identifiers</sup>

If you want to make use of quoted identifiers, you will have to store all values in a map, something like:

```
def map = [:]
map."trigger-${cname}" = true

assert map."trigger-${cname}"
```